# Why didn't the students escape fire through windows?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-boy

In *The Boy (2015)* towards the final act of the movie, we see Ted locking the doors of the motel rooms, then pouring gasoline onto the doors, before setting them on fire.

Later we hear the students cry and scream of agony, since they are locked inside and can't escape.

But why didn't any of them try to escape from the windows?

Earlier in the movie, we see Ted sneaking into one of the rooms through a window, which means these windows are not bared, and can allow a human to pass through.

Is this a plot hole? or are we supposed to assume that the students were too drunk to be able to think their way out of a burning room?